# TCP vs Shared Memory?

Tags: c++

I understand, if shared memory is used correctly it can be faster than any other kind of IPC. My question is a bit more specific: If I transfer many small packets, eg 100 bytes, from different programs to one main program, what kind of speed difference can I expect?

Comment: Why don't you test it?  It sounds like a very straightforward test...

Comment: A related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101671/unix-domain-sockets-vs-shared-memory-mapped-file) from a more lenient time.

Comment: "Speed" Could mean bytes per sec, messages per sec, latency or Even CPU load... And all are totally dependant on your code. So test it if you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit from using shared memory will not be so much, because you will end up with using conditional variables on the shared memory (cf. `pthread_condattr_setpshared`; it will be a substantial coding work, by the way.)  Then your logic is governed by the OS scheduler, and it's not very different from using `localhost` TCP connection which has a different and fast implementation than standard TCP on most OS.

If it's OK to entirely rely on a spinlock on the shared mem, then you will indeed realize substantial speed up like x3 fold.