# How to share cv::Mat for processing between cpp and python using shared memory

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost, windows-10

I am using shared memory provided by boost/interprocess/ to share the cv::Mat between model and client (both C++). Now I need to use a model in Python. Can you please tell which is the best way to share the cv::Mat between C++ and Python without changing the present client. Thanks.

Comment: What's your platform? Since shared memory might be platform specific.

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257364/4123703)

Comment: @LouisGo I am working in Windows 10.

Comment: [Multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) seems good for you.

Comment: @LouisGo Thank you for the comments. I will check multiprocessing.shared_memory. Currently I was able to solve it using mapped memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task was completed using mapped memory to share the cv::Mat between C++ and Python process.

- C++ - use boost to copy cv::Mat to a mapped shared memory

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
imgMat= cv::imread("image.jpg");

windows_shared_memory shmem(open_or_create, "shm", read_write, img_size);

mapped_region region(shmem, read_write);

unsigned char* img_ptr = static_cast<unsigned char*> (region.get_address());

std::memcpy(img_ptr , imgMat.data, img_size);

std::system("pause");
}
```

- Python - read the image from memory using mmap.

```
import mmap
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
  shmem = mmap.mmap(-1, image_size ,"shm")
  shmem.seek(0)
  buf = shmem.read(image_size)
  img = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
  cv.imwrite("img.png", img)
  shmem.close()
```

Comment: Would https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html be better for this, or is mmap better?

Comment: @kevinlinxc : It did not work for me for a cross platform solution. I tried and explained that here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091769/fast-communication-between-c-and-python-using-shared-memory/